# Objective C - iOS - Dealloc is being called in middle of execution of webViewDidFinishLoad

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am having an issue with memory management in ios. The problem is when I push a viewController which has a webView on to the navigation stack and when I click back before the webview is loaded I am getting exec_bad_access.

In 'Class A' I am creating a NewViewController, then I am pushing it on to the navigation stack, and then releasing it. So here I am giving away my ownership as I am releasing it.

Class A:

```
-(void)onButtonClick{
    NewViewController* viewController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController........];
    [viewController release];
}
```

Class B has a webView and a timer in it and implements UIWebViewDelegate. So, in here when the webView shouldStartLoad I am starting the timer. And then when it is done loading I am invalidating it.

Class B:

```
@interface NewViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
    NSTimer* timer
    ......
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;
@end

@implementation
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [webView loadRequest:someRequest];
}
.....
.....
-(void)dealloc{
  [self makeTimerNil];
  [self.webView stoploading];
  self.webView.delegate = nil;
  [self.webView release];
  self.webView = nil;
  .....
  [super dealloc];
}

-(void)resetTimer{
    [self makeTimerNil];
    //timer will retain target - self
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kNetworkTimeOut target:self selector:@selector(networkTimedOut) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)makeTimerNil{
    if([timer isValid]){
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    [self resetTimer];
    ......
    return YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    //NO Exception. Can access self
    [self anotherMethod];
    //timer releases retained target -self
    [self makeTimerNil];
    //Exception self has been deallocated
    [self anotherMethod];
}
@end
```

But the issue is when the webView is loading if I click back button on the navigation bar, the newViewController is getting deallocated which is fine. But this is happening in the middle of execution of webViewDidFinishLoad. Why is dealloc being called in the middle of execution of webViewDidFinishLoad? Don't they run on the same thread (Main - UI Thread) ?

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Comment: My suspicion (although I can't make sure not having an older SDK than 5.0 on this machine) is that the only thing that holds a reference to your viewcontroller is the Timer. When you do [timer invalidate], the timer is released and it in its turn releases your viewcontroller causing dealloc.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Yes, that right. Timer is holding on to the viewController and once it is invalidated it is releasing the viewController.

Comment: The invalidate documentation says; "The NSRunLoop object removes and releases the timer, either just before the invalidate method returns or at some later point." so that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is absolutely the timer. According to the NSTimer documentation, an active timer holds a retain on its target object. As a result, your controller *cannot* get dealloc'd while the timer is active. That in itself is a bug in your architecture, since from your `-dealloc` method it's obvious you're expecting the view controller to be dealloc'd while the timer is active. But in the case of the webview, it's causing another problem. Specifically, in the middle of your `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` method you're canceling your timer. This causes it to release its target, and since it was the only owner of your view controller, the view controller immediately deallocs.

Comment: Voted up, as I think this is correct.  Deleting my previous answer since its not really relevant to the OP's issue.  (After you reply to my comment b/c I'm curious!)

Comment: @Kevin Ballard: Thanks for the reply. That is absolutely correct. I am trying to figure out what I can do to fix this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sai: The best way is to stop relying on `dealloc` to trigger logic. You could add a `-teardown` method to your VC that is called when the VC is no longer needed. Or you could kill the timer in `-viewDidDisappear:` as others have suggested. However if you need the `-dealloc` logic, you could use a helper object whose sole job is to forward the timer invocation to your main class, and then the timer can point to the helper instead. That avoids the retain on your VC, and in your `-dealloc` you can cancel the timer and throw away the helper object.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard - Thanks. I added seperate class to handle the timer. Workes perfectly for now.

Comment: We have a similar issue, and this is the first time i realized that `self` can become an invalid reference in the middle of a method invocation. Shudder. Looks like delegate methods are a hot candidate for that trap.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This post is wrong and irrelevant to the OP.  Struck-out the misleading text. Leaving rest here because I learned something in comments from Kevin below, and it may help someone else!**

---

<strike>IF you don't need the webViewDidFinishLoad handling to occur on dealloc, set `self.webView.delegate = nil;` before calling `stopLoading`.</strike>

Also, you could manually call the webViewDidFinishLoad handling in the dealloc if any of it is needed and doesn't depend on the state of the webView.

I really wouldn't recommend putting a `stopLoading` in your dealloc.  Just set the delegate to nil.

You should not design your dealloc to launch a lot of logic -- If your object is receiving a dealloc before its finished handling the logic you expect it to, then you are allowing it to be released it too quickly.

Comment: I agree that launching logic in dealloc is something you should avoid, but other than that, your advice is wrong. Calling `-stopLoading` on the webview before nilling out the delegate *will not* cause `-webViewDidFinishLoading:` to call. The reason being, `-stopLoading` is asynchronous, but nilling out the delegate is synchronous. By the time the `-stopLoading` actually decides to stop loading, the delegate is nilled out and *cannot* receive any messages.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't it still possible for `webViewDidFinishLoading:` to be called before the delegate is set to nil since they are two separate lines?  Or not possible if everything is on the same RunLoop?

Comment: The delegate method is always called on the main thread. Therefore it cannot "interrupt" the `-dealloc` and get called in between the `-stopLoading` and the `webView.delegate = nil`. It may only be called after control returns to the runloop (at which point the delegate is nil). The only way it could still be called is if webkit queries the webview's delegate, saves it, and then invokes the method on that saved object on the main thread, but it's highly unlikely that it behaves this way.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks much @KevinBallard !  (Decided to keep post b/c this was useful information to me.)

Answer (score 0):

`dealloc` will be called when the retain count drops to 0 and will happen immediately, not later on. It is happening on the thread that the count drops to 0 in, in your case the thread that `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is called in.

One this you could do here is to add a `[self retain]` at the top of your `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method and a `[self release]` at the bottom of it. However I'm not 100% sure if that method is guaranteed to run on the main thread and if a view controller gets dealloc'ed on a thread other than the main thread then there can be lots of problems.

To fix this really, I would override `viewDidDisappear:` and do all the tearing down of the web view there (i.e. setting the delegate to nil and stopping the timer, etc). That way it'll happen on the main thread and at the point you tap the back button.

Comment: Instead of overriding     viewDidDisappear, I have that code in viewWillUnload and its still the same.

Comment: @Sai - `viewWillUnload` is iOS 5 only and is **not** called when the view goes off screen. It's just called when a low memory situation occurs and the view is unloaded. You can't rely on it being called.

Comment: All webview delegate methods *always* run on the main thread.

Comment: I am hesitating to do that because I don't want to stop the webview or make the webview's delegate nil on view disappear. Because all the code I have in NewViewController is actullay in a AbstractViewController. I have both navigation controller and tabbar controller in the app. If I use viewWillDisappear it will affect the viewcontrollers in tabbar controller. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: OK, but you can't use `viewWillUnload`. You should know the scenarios that cause your view controller to disappear and handle them accordingly. If it's just when back is tapped, then you might need to look at `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to determine this.

Comment: @KevinBallard - OK, sure, but I rarely want to just assume that. I don't believe there are docs to say that they *always* run on the main thread.

Comment: @mattjgalloway: They do. Trust me, they absolutely do. If it helps you to be comfortable with this, UIWebView is a component of UIKit, and a view to boot, and therefore all interaction with it *must* occur on the main thread (this is one of the requirements of UIKit and view programming).

Comment: @KevinBallard it's a fair point you make and I'm basically being very cautious in this answer. In reality I take the same line as you mention about it's a UIKit view so it'll happen on the main thread. And it's true that the real fix here is to fix the logic of the timer.

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly nil'ing out the web view's delegate in -dealloc.

I *think* (but this might be wrong) that, as UI delegate methods, the web view delegate methods will always come in on the main thread, so that shouldn't be an issue.  Nowhere else would threading come into play here.

Something that strikes me as a possible problem, though, is unrelated to your web view code per se.

Consider the interaction between

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;
```

and

```
[self.webView release];
self.webView = nil;
```

Since you have declared webView as retained, won't self.webView = nil send a release to webView (and retain to nil, which of course doesn't do anything)?  Isn't this then an over-release of webView?

(As a general rule, you shouldn't use accessors in init/dealloc, in part due to side-effects.)

EDIT:

To examine this further, I wrote a quick test using the view-based app template.  Relevant portions below:

```
// In MyClass.m
+ (id)alloc
{
    NSLog(@"alloc");
    return [super alloc];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
    [super dealloc];
}

- (oneway void)release
{
    NSLog(@"release");
    [super release];
}

- (id)retain
{
    NSLog(@"retain");
    return [super retain];
}


// In UIViewController subclass
// .h:
#import "MyClass.h"
@property (retain, nonatomic) MyClass *myObj;
// .m:
@synthesize myObj = _myObj;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setMyObj:[[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease]];
    [self setMyObj:nil];
}
```

This produced the following output, indicating that setting nil does, as I expected, release the old object:

```
2012-01-30 11:04:37.277 ReleaseTest[56305:f803] alloc
2012-01-30 11:04:37.278 ReleaseTest[56305:f803] retain
2012-01-30 11:04:37.279 ReleaseTest[56305:f803] release
2012-01-30 11:04:37.282 ReleaseTest[56305:f803] release
2012-01-30 11:04:37.283 ReleaseTest[56305:f803] dealloc
```

An, unsurprisingly, adding an extraneous release crashed the app with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setMyObj:[[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease]];
    [[self myObj] release];
    [self setMyObj:nil];
}

2012-01-30 11:06:22.815 ReleaseTest[56330:f803] alloc
2012-01-30 11:06:22.817 ReleaseTest[56330:f803] retain
2012-01-30 11:06:22.818 ReleaseTest[56330:f803] release
2012-01-30 11:06:22.818 ReleaseTest[56330:f803] release
2012-01-30 11:06:22.819 ReleaseTest[56330:f803] dealloc

objc_release --> EXC_BAD_ACCESS in UIApplicationMain()
```

Of course, the code behaves identically if dot syntax is used (though dot syntax has the unfortunate effect of concealing the fact that it uses accessors, which is one reason I don't use it).  I also tested by using an IBOutlet instead of instantiating in code.  A lot more retain/releases, again unsurprisingly, but still a crash if I include an extra release:

```
2012-01-30 11:09:59.631 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] alloc
2012-01-30 11:09:59.633 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] retain
2012-01-30 11:09:59.634 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] retain
2012-01-30 11:09:59.635 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] retain
2012-01-30 11:09:59.636 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] retain
2012-01-30 11:09:59.636 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] retain
2012-01-30 11:09:59.637 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] release
2012-01-30 11:09:59.638 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] release
2012-01-30 11:09:59.638 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] release
2012-01-30 11:09:59.639 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] release
2012-01-30 11:09:59.640 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] release
2012-01-30 11:09:59.641 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] release
2012-01-30 11:09:59.641 ReleaseTest[56389:f803] dealloc

objc_msgSend --> EXC_BAD_ACCESS in UIApplicationMain()
```

So, in conclusion, I believe you do have a memory management error in your code, and this is responsible for some, if not all, of your crashes (which, I note, are of the same kind that I experimentally reproduced).

Comment: self.webView = nil doesn't send a release to webView.

Comment: @ConradShultz: This doesn't explain the OP's question, but it's absolutely correct, he does have a memory issue. Calling `self.webView = nil` in his code *will* release the webview. One key recommendation here is saying `[self.webview release]` is ***ALWAYS*** wrong regardless of your memory semantics. You *never* call an accessor (in this case, `self.webview`) and then call `-release` on the results. It's just plain wrong.

Comment: @KevinBallard Yup, that's a point I have made (apparently in vain) here and elsewhere. :-(

Comment: I will change that to [webView release] instead of [self.webView release];

Comment: @Sai You also will need to change self.webView = nil to webView = nil.  The fix you indicated will not actually prevent the over-release.  The over-release occurs because using the accessor ([self setWebView]) releases the previous object.

Comment: yes, I meant I would change all the instances of self.webview to webview in my dealloc. Thanks for the helping me out with this guys.