# Objective-C ARC - does a method retain 'self'?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Is this a safe thing to do?

```
__weak typeof (self) welf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [welf doStuff];
})

....

-(void)doStuff {
    [_member1 someMethod];
    ....
    [_member2 someMethodWithParam:_someCArray[1];];
}
```

As far as I understand ARC, the actual call to `[welf doStuff]` should be fine, as `welf` will either be valid (and the method call will proceed), or it will be `nil` - calling any method on `nil` is defined safe behaviour in Objective-C so that seems ok.

Once we get into `doStuff` however, does ARC cause `self` to be retained for the duration of the method call? If it does, I think we should be ok... If not, then `self` could get `dealloc`'ed halfway through the method call and then we'd be in a bad spot.

Note: I googled for this but couldn't find anything obvious. Perhaps it's just hard to search for?

Thanks!

Comment: @YuriiKolesnykov I don't see how that questions answers this one.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question. The other question focuses on retain cycles.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out I found the answer eventually, both here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18011581/234 and here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#self

`self` is always `unsafe unretained` under ARC, so in my example, it would NOT be safe, and there would be nothing to stop it getting deallocated partway through my `doStuff` method. Ouch

Comment: Your example is ok because welf is essentially retained once doStuff is called until doStuff returns.